# using list in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

```
transactions_clean = []
for transac in daily_transactions_split:
    transaction_clean = []
    for tran in transac:
        transaction_clean.append(tran.replace("\n", "").strip(" "))
    transactions_clean.append(transaction_clean)
```

can anyone please explain why the author created `transaction_clean = []` ?? While he/she can directly append the stripped value to `transactions_clean`?

Comment: You haven't made a [mcve], but it looks like `daily_transactions_split` (not defined) is a list-of-lists, and using `transaction_clean` makes `transactions_clean` also a list-of-lists.  Directly appending to `transactions_clean` would only make a simple list.

Answer (score 0):

The author is creating a list of lists:

```
[['this', 'is'], ['a', 'list'], ['of', 'lists']]
```

Note it would be cleaner to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.12/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20compre#list-comprehensions) to create the child lists:

```
transactions_clean = []
for transac in daily_transactions_split:
    transaction_clean = [tran.replace("\n", "").strip(" ") for tran in transac]
    transactions_clean.append(transaction_clean)
```

If you want to get really fancy, double-up on the comprehensions:

```
transactions_clean = [[tran.replace("\n", "").strip(" ") for tran in transac] for transac in daily_transactions_split]
```